# Reference element of in another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code, if I have a variable that points to `have_this`, how can I reference `select_this` with JQuery?

```
<div class="ds">
  <div class="di">
    <a class="have_this" href="example.com"></a>
  </div>
  <ul class="tg">
    <li class="select_this"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: There are many `.select_this` on the page, I need to reference the one in the parent.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing which things are constant. Are there always only one `div` and one `ul` with one `li` in `.ds`?  Do they always have those class names?

Comment: DOM traversal is a basic and fundamental part of using jQuery. You should read some introductory learning materials so that you don't need to ask someone else every time you want to perform a simple task.

Comment: There are many `ds` on the page with this same structure.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `$have_this` is the variable. Try this:

```
var $have_this = $("a.have_this");
$have_this.parent("div").siblings("ul").find("li.select_this").text();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/GLzgk/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$(your_var).parent().next().find('li.select_this')
```

Depending on how you're getting your have_this variable, you may or may not need to wrap it in $().

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
have_this_var.parent().next().find('.select_this');
```

Answer (score 1):

If structure will remain same you can do:

```
$(".have_this").closest("div.di").next('ul').find("li.select_this");
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `select_this` isn't a class:

```
$have_this.closest('.ds').find('.tg li');
```